# How to create a multi objective particle swarm optimization in Matlab?

Tags: particle-swarm

How can I write a multi objective cost function using two equations given below for particle swarm optimization

X(n+1)=AY (n) + BU + I &
Y(n)=0.5*(abs(X(n)+1)-abs(X(n)-1))

Where A & B are 3*3 matrices.